# Consistency of "Adding Amplitudes" and Normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, normalization, born-rule

Consider two particles ($ a $ and $ b $) colliding and scattering elastically at right angles (calling paths 1, 2; up and down, respectively). 
The problem is to work out the probabilities of this happening for identical bosonic particles.

This question relates to chapter 3 and 4 of [The Feynman Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_03.html) Vol. 3.

Given the initial state $ \left |ab \right \rangle $ and the possible final states $ \left | 12 \right \rangle $ and $ \left | 21 \right \rangle $, the probability of measuring a particle in the vertical direction is (according to Feynman):
$$p = \left | \left \langle 12 | ab \right \rangle + \left \langle 21|ab \right \rangle \right|^2$$

I am confused because the final state (for which a measurement would be made) is the superposition $\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left ( \left | 12 \right \rangle + \left | 21 \right \rangle \right )$, where the $\sqrt{2}$ factor is necessary for normalization.
However, this would lead to a probability (of the state to be taken)
$$p = \left | \left \langle \psi|ab \right \rangle \right |^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left | \left \langle 12|ab \right \rangle + \left \langle 21|ab \right \rangle \right|^2$$

It seems I am making a conceptual mistake somewhere. Any thoughts on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: My first thought is that the initial state should symmetrized and normalized too, but that doesn't help your question. I think Feynman is just trying to avoid talking about states at this point.

Comment: Good point @Javier , I did not think about that. However, |ab> could just be redefined as the symmetric state which would lead to the same equations. My main point of concern is that for <12|ab>=<21|ab> (due to symmetry) the second probability is p=2|<12|ab>|^2, which is the same as for non-identical particles (p=|<12|ab>|^2+|<21|ab>|^2). Every source I could find states the probability for bosons is twice that.